# Google Home - how to detect user name

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

How to detect username/email associated with google account from Google home?
i would like to use this name/email in greetings.

for example,
If user say, "OK google, Good Morning"
expecting below reply from  Google home,
"Good Morning user , how I can help you?" (user replaced with actual name )

Also tried to create intent in api.ai but need to provide name first and then GH will use that name in reply.  GH shouldn't speak user's name from its associated google account.

Answer (score 1):

For names, you can use the permissions [documented here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information). Also take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-name-psychic-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js#L111).

Emails are currently not supported without using [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/).

Comment: sample link is dead

Comment: Fixed. Apologies about that.